# Override a mapping with leader key

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to create a mapping that has 2 functions:

On 1st use: redefine itself to be used

After: execute the newly saved mapping

The workflow could be :

`<leader>r` -> `map <leader>r dd`

`<leader>r` -> `dd`

`<leader>r` -> `dd`

...

So I came up with this mapping :

`map <Leader>r :nnoremap <Leader>r`

And I get :

`<leader>r` -> `:nnoremap  r`

My leader key is `\<Space>`  and so a space is inserted and now I can trigger the mapping but with only pressing `r`.

Do you know a method to "escape" the leader key in a mapping ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a mapping, escape `<` with `<lt>` (and `|` with `<Bar>`). The following example shows a working demo of your idea:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>r :nnoremap <lt>Leader>r :echo "hi"<lt>CR><CR>
```

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) for the initial mapping, too.

Answer (score 4):

From reading the Vim source, it would seem that all occurrences of `<Leader>` in a mapping are replaced by the leader character, you can't escape this. From `term.c` `replace_keycodes()` (abbreviated):

```
if (strncmp(src, "<Leader>", 8) == 0) {
    p = get_var_value("g:mapleader");
}
```

I only did a quick reading, so perhaps I missed something.

---

The easiest workaround I can figure out is using a character code to "hide" the `<Leader>` part from this piece of code, which seems to run *before* the code that replaces the character codes:

```
map <Leader>r :nnoremap <Char-0x3c>Leader>r
```

`<Char-0x3c>` is the hex code for the `<` character.

---

Note I didn't know about the `<Char-` syntax either by the way, I found it by typing [`:help key-mapping`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#key-mapping); at the top of the page there's an index and the "Mapping special keys" and "Special characters" sections looked interesting enough to skim, which is where I found this ;-)

Comment: thanks for your answer and for the link to the documentation :)