# How to read the value of Maplocalleader?

Tags: key-bindings

The command `map localleader` are explained very nicely [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/06.html). How do I read the current value of the `<localleader>` thingy? Is this a variable or what?

Comment: Global variables: `echo g:mapleader` `echo g:maplocalleader` (usually you can skip the `g:`). Hint: you can also set them :D

Comment: @VanLaser, don't be shy; post answers.

Comment: But, but .. they are SO simple :( I do encourage the author of the question to post the answer himself/herself, in a good quality format.

Comment: @VanLaser You could expand your answer and explain what's the use of this key. Even though I've already read the page linked by the author of the question, I've never quite understood what's the benefit of this key compared to the `<leader>` key.

Comment: I could, but this information is available already.

Comment: You're right sorry, it's only for certain filetypes. I rarely see it used so I forgot.

Comment: No need to apologize :) What I mean is, I don't *like* writing long answers, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @VanLaser Amen brother!

Comment: Once you know what maplocalleader is set to, you might want to know what key mappings are set up to use it, in which case refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082313/show-all-leader-mappings

Answer (score 3):

From [`:h maplocalleader`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#maplocalleader):

```
                                        <LocalLeader> maplocalleader
<LocalLeader> is just like <Leader>, except that it uses "maplocalleader"
instead of "mapleader".  <LocalLeader> is to be used for mappings which are
local to a buffer.
```

Recursing on to `:h <Leader>` (which is just above this paragraph):

```
                                        <Leader> mapleader
To define a mapping which uses the "mapleader" variable, the special string
"<Leader>" can be used.  It is replaced with the string value of "mapleader".
If "mapleader" is not set or empty, a backslash is used instead.  Example: 
        :map <Leader>A  oanother line<Esc>
Works like: 
        :map \A  oanother line<Esc>
But after: 
        :let mapleader = ","
It works like: 
        :map ,A  oanother line<Esc>
```

So, `mapleader` *is* a variable, and therefore `maplocalleader` is too.

The tricky part, of course, is that neither is set by default - and so Vim uses `\` as the leader. If you try to examine the value of these two variables, by e.g., `let maplocalleader` or `echo mapleader`, Vim will just throw an error:

```
E121: Undefined variable: mapleader
```

How do you set it? The `<Leader>` help quoted above has an example:

```
let mapleader = ","
```

Similarly, for example:

```
let maplocalleader = "_"
```

Comment: And, how do you inspect its value?

Comment: @YossiGil `let maplocalleader` or `echo maplocalleader`, as I have already mentioned.

Comment: I edited the answer so that this would be more explicit.

Comment: Note that Vim will always expand the current value of `mapleader`/`maplocalleader` when it's used, and that re-setting the value to something else will **not** affect any previous instances of its usage, so getting the current value of `mapleader` may not reflect the value that Vim actually used to expand the key mappings (see the [code example here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3135/51)).